# Accessing a database through a user in snowflake

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can access my databases using this script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import inspect
 
engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account_identifier}/'.format(
        user  = ACCOUNTNAME
        password   = ACCOUNTPASSWORD
        account_identifier = 'xy12345.eu-west-1.aws', 
    )
)
try:
    connection = engine.connect()
    results = connection.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
    print(results[0])
finally:
    connection.close()
    insp    = inspect(engine)
```

Which is largely similar to what is presented in the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html).

However, I'd like to do this without using my name and password. As a result, I set up a user with their own username and password. When I run the code with their username and password I get:

```
DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: br54387.eu-west-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
```

How should I connect if not this way?
The only thing I can think of is that I should be using a different account name when i am trying to access the database through this user, but i can't find one either in the documentation or in my `USERS` table

Comment: Can you successfully log into the Snowflake UI with this second username/password?

Comment: I am not sure, when i try to log in it asks me for my account/password not user or username /password. If I give it the user username it tells me invalid account

Comment: When you go to your Snowflake URL (e.g. <<account>>.<<region>>.snowflakecomputing.com ) in your browser it should show a page that says "Sign in to Snowflake" and below that boxes for Username and Password. Is this not what you see?

Comment: i didn't realise i had to log in through that URL; doing that I get username/password and if i use the login_name/password of the user I've created it works. However, i created a role with access to a db, and assigned that role to the user and the user is still not able to see the db when i log in as them

Comment: Is that the only role the user has? When you log into the UI have you set the context of the worksheet to that role?

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it!